# how to Print arraylist in jsp using java method

Tags: java, jsp

This is Java class:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class sample {

    public void print() {

        ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        l.add("a");
        l.add("b");

    }
}
```

This is my Jsp page :

```
<%@page import="java.awt.List"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ page import="com.example.sample"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    sample s = new sample();
%>


</body>
</html>
```

I dont know how to call print merhod and how Print list in jsp page so that i print data in jsp page list please help me how i will Implement i am learning this.

Comment: You can use JSTL, its easy to use, just search for it

Comment: You need to return the list to JSP file. Use `out.print()` to print on web page.

Comment: No i have to do using java method plz write code i have use iterator but not understanding.i am beginner

Comment: It would be best to add the List as an attribute in a request passed to a servlet.  From the servlet forward to the jsp and print the list with jstl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First return a list from print method

```
public List<String> print() {

        ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        l.add("a");
        l.add("b");

     return l;

    }
```

Don't use scriplets, Use JSTL

```
<%
    sample s = new sample(); //not recommended.Pass this object from servlet
    List<String> list = s.print();
%>
```

with that print where ever you want to print in `jsp`

With `JSTL`

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
    ${item}<br>
</c:forEach>
```

**With scriplets (not recommended);**

```
<% for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
          {

              out.println(list.get(i));

          } %>
```

**With help of `iterator`;**

```
 <%  Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {    
        out.println(<iterator.next());
    }
 %>
```

Side note:Not tested ,and  make sure that you have imported all used classes in **JSP**.

Comment: I have to use Iterator .

Comment: @user2837886 Why do you *have* to?

Comment: I dont need to Use for each an all In jsp page i have to Print using iterator as while loop.

Comment: NOt getting Output please complete this I am totally new in this

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
Class c = new Class(); 
List<String> list = c.print();
for (c : list) {
  //print list here
}
%>
```